# How can I log in to an API and catch login errors using fetch on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making an application that requires login to an API. I have a login form which sends the ID number and password to the API, and the API should respond like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "user_id":"032984",
      "user_number":"140521351",
      "token":"990nZtMtEUUMY"
   }
]
```

If there is a login error, the API responds with:

```
[
  {
    "ERROR": "INVALID PASSWORD | NOT FOUND 1SELECT user_id, lastname, password, user_number FROM user where user_number = 'INVALIDVALUE'",
  },
]
```

I want to be able to catch a login error with an if statement, like if there is the ERROR object in this JSON, display an alert, else login and save the user_id and token to variables I can use in different screens of the app to send more requests to the API, get those responses in JSON, and show the data I need.

How can I make this happen?

So far, here's the code for my login function:

```
// login function
  _userLogin = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoggingIn: true, message: '' });

    // send request to API properly
    fetch("https://api.company.com/v4/users/json.php", {
      method: "POST",
      // our headers
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Connection': 'close',
          'Accept': '*/*',
          'User-Agent': 'InternalApp/0.1 (InternalApp; ReactNative) Expo/33',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=1.0',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
      },
      // body of the request with number/password
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_number: this.state.number,
        password: this.state.password,
      }),
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json(); // make it json?!
    }).then(responseData => {
      // debug messages
      console.log(responseData);
      console.log("Moving on to parsing JSON"); // CODE WORKS TO HERE

      // parse json
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(responseData); // CODE STUCK HERE
      // debug messages
      console.log("JSON parsed");
      if (jsonObj.ERROR)
        console.log("Error caught");
      else
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          credentialJson: prevState.credentialJson = responseData,
          isLoggingIn: false,
        }))

      this.props.onLoginPress();
    })
  };
```

I'm really new to React Native and StackOverflow, please excuse any formatting issues with the question. I hope I've provided enough detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments to this answer and the output of `console.log(responseData)` your responseData is an Array and your data is an Object inside the first array element. Access your data through `responseData[0]`. For example:

```
responseData[0].token
//Should return "990nZtMtEUUMY"
```

Here is how you would check if there is an error set:

```
if(responseData[0].ERROR){}
```

Comment: The code is stuck at `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(responseData);` so `jsonObj` isn't even a valid variable yet.

Comment: `Array [
  Object {
    "user_id": "032984",
    "user_number": "140521351",
    "token": "990nZtMtEUUMY",
  },
]`

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch library `fetch` returns a `Promise` so if the API actually throws an error you can add a catch statement.

```
fetch(url).then().catch((error) => {
   console.log("Error", error);
});
```

The other thing is the reason your code is halting at JSON.parse is that you already parsed the json in a previous `.then` clause (`response.json()`) so your trying to parse an object, not a string, which `JSON.parse` expects.

Comment: The API gives 200 OK as a response even when there's an error. For the JSON.parse error solution, how could I implement that in my code? Would I just remove the `.then` clause with `response.json()`? Sorry if this sounds stupid, again, I'm really new to React Native and don't know much about it.